# How to scroll Recylerview inside bottom sheet while keeping bottom sheet in desired state?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a persistent bottom sheet inside coordinate layout. I have set bottomsheethideable = true and implemented BottomSheetBehaviour callbacks. Currently, bottom sheet opens in the collapsed mode and when I am scrolling recylerview inside view pager of bottomsheet . BottomSheet also scrolled up that is the default behavior of bottomsheet. I want to keep bottom sheet in collapsed stated utill i reached at last position of recylerview and after then bottomsheet should scroll up and required opposite behavior too.

Inside bottom sheet, there is a  view pager. Here is XML file code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:transitionName="app_bar_layout">

                <com.appstreet.pixylz.view.ASToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/tb_top"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBarTheme" />


            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
            layout="@layout/layout_browser_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bar_ht_with_9path_shadow"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Someone suggested to create custom BottomSheetBehaviour and disable TouchEvents using return false **onTouchEvent** and **onInterceptTouchEvent** inside CustomBottomSheetBehaviour. Using this RecylerView Scrolled and BottomSheet also stayed on collapsed position but on end of recylerview scroll. BottomSheet doesn't dragged Up or Down even sliding outside of recylerview bottomsheet is not dragging.

Anyone can help or suggest solution? Thanks.

Comment: set fix height of bottom layout

Comment: @Arbaz.in if I will set fix height of bottom layout then how will I expand bottom sheet on inner recylerview scroll (after reaching the last item)?